# Distribute, epydoc, and setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py, epydoc

I would like to have a target (say `docs`) that runs epydoc for my package.  I assume that I need to create a new command but I am not having much luck.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Babel project](http://babel.edgewall.org/) provides several commands for use in `setup.py` files.

You need to define a `distutils.commands` entry point with commands; example from the [Babel `setup.py` file](http://babel.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/setup.py#L32):

```
entry_points = """
[distutils.commands]
compile_catalog = babel.messages.frontend:compile_catalog
extract_messages = babel.messages.frontend:extract_messages
init_catalog = babel.messages.frontend:init_catalog
update_catalog = babel.messages.frontend:update_catalog
"""
```

where the extra commands are then available as `python setup.py commandname`.

The entry points point to subclasses of `from distutils.cmd import Command`. Example again from Babel, from the [`babel.messages.frontend` module](http://babel.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/babel/messages/frontend.py):

```
from distutils.cmd import Command
from distutils.errors import DistutilsOptionError


class compile_catalog(Command):
    """Catalog compilation command for use in ``setup.py`` scripts."""

    # Description shown in setup.py --help-commands
    description = 'compile message catalogs to binary MO files'
    # Options available for this command, tuples of ('longoption', 'shortoption', 'help')
    # If the longoption name ends in a `=` it takes an argument
    user_options = [
        ('domain=', 'D',
         "domain of PO file (default 'messages')"),
        ('directory=', 'd',
         'path to base directory containing the catalogs'),
        # etc.
    ]
    # Options that don't take arguments, simple true or false options.
    # These *must* be included in user_options too, but without a = equals sign
    boolean_options = ['use-fuzzy', 'statistics']

    def initialize_options(self):
        # Set a default for each of your user_options (long option name)

    def finalize_options(self):
        # verify the arguments and raise DistutilOptionError if needed

    def run(self):
        # Do your thing here.
```